# How do I use a column other than Title for a Quick Chart label?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, chart-web-part

I have a custom list in SharePoint Online that is setup with the following fields:

- Department (choices list)
- PPE Type (choices list)
- Amount (number)

On the home page of the site that contains this list, I would like to create a Quick Chart showing the PPE Types selected and the amount of each.

I know one of the axes or label types needs to be a Numerical column (that's "*Amount*", in this case). However, I can only seem to use "*Title*" as the other axis or label, regardless of what type of chart I pick (see both options below):

[image: Column chart showing "title" only] [image: Pie chart showing "title" only]

The issue is that each item in my list has a blank Title field, because I set it to Hidden. I turned on Management of Content Types to hide the "Title" field because there's no value in having an additional arbitrary text field per entry for this list, which will see hundreds of entries per day by as many users.

I considered changing the *Title* column to represent my PPE Type column, but you can't change the column type for *Title*. I also considered using a lookup or calculated column, but neither of those worked for the Quick chart, either, despite setting the ultimate display type to 'single line of text' for them.

How can I choose a different column other than Title for my Quick chart's non-numerical axis/label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you only see *Title* in the second axis list and not *PPE Type* is because it is the only field on your list that is a "single line of text" data type; Microsoft has not added support yet for different column types beyond "single line of text" and "number".

In fact, as of this writing not everyone has even received the feature rollout to connect a Quick Chart to a SharePoint list (though that rollout should complete soon).

There was a [UserVoice suggestion](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026194515/https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36560149-enable-choice-fields-for-quick-charts) for supporting Choice fields in the hopes of getting Microsoft to add support for this. I do not know at this time whether the feature was ever added, or if a similar feature request exists on whatever replaced UserVoice.